# Screen sharing with x11vnc + noVNC

Tags: linux, remote-access, vnc, screen-sharing

**Context & Goal**
I have a small embedded device running Linux armv71. My goal is to remotely access the screen through a web browser with a mobile device. I have x11vnc running which I thought supported access through web browsers but I couldn't get it to work until I was told I needed a proxy for web access. I was recommended noVNC so here I am trying to get this to work :p

**The Problem**
I can't access the noVNC login page with a mobile phone. WebSockets proxy fails to start.

**More Info**
I first startup x11vnc (I have a copy of the output if it helps) and then I launch novnc which gives the following output:
[image]

I thought typing in my web browser (chrome) the URL given by novnc (< remoteIP>:5900) would connect but I just get an invalid response. However, if I type "< remoteIP>/vnc.html", I get to the noVNC login screen and from there I have access to my screen. Great so far!

When I try to access the noVNC login page with my iPhone6 using Safari, I don't get a response from the server. I guess the problem is with the WebSockets proxy failing to start ...

My (Windows) computer and my remote device are on the same networks so that's probably why I can connect with my computer but not with my phone. 
Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any other fools like me who runs into this problem, the solution is as simple as having the server and client devices on the same network.

I still don't know why the WebSockets proxy failed to start or what it does ...